# MongoDb Structure Error

Tags: c#, mongodb, winforms

I have those classes

```
public class UserWatchTblCls
{
    [BsonId]
    [BsonElement("_id")]
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("fbId")]
    public string fbId { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("pass")]
    public string Pass { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("Watchtbl")]
    public List<WatchTblCls> WatchTbls { get; set; }
}

public class WatchTblCls
{
    [BsonElement("wid")]
    public string WID { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [BsonElement("Symboles")]
    public List<SymboleCls> Symbols { get; set; }
}

public class SymboleCls
{
    [BsonElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I need to know how I can represent it on mongoDB in just one collection.
I have a few models

> This one is the original that I am inserting directly into mongodb and works.

```
    db.UsersWatchtbls.insert( { 
fbId: "", 
Name: "user1", 
pass: "pass1",
Watchtbl: 
    [ 
        { 
        wid: "1350",
        name: "bought stock1",
        Symboles: [ { Name: "AAA" }, { Name: "BSI" } ] 
        },
        { 
        wid: "1350",
        name: "bought stock2",
        Symboles: [ { Name: "AAA" }, { Name: "BSI" }, { Name: "EXXI" } ] 
        }
    ]
} )
```

> But If I use the code bellow with "Watchtbl is BsonDocument will show this structure

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57f6182f5ced692478860b04"), "fbId" : "", "Name" : "user7", "pass" : "user7", "Watchtbl" : { "wid" : "", "name" : "", "Symboles" : [ { "Name" : "" } ] } }
```

> And if I modify Watchtbl to BsonArray, will show this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("57f4d3d55ced692da4a4c3d2"), "fbId" : "", "Name" : "user1", "pass" : "user1", "Watchtbl" : [ { "wid" : "" }, { "name" : "" }, { "Symboles" : [ { "Name" : "" } ] } ] }
```

But I facing some problem with inserting details when I insert new user, so I most put the watchtbl list empty or null, this my code:

```
private async void Registerbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://servername:27017");

            var database = client.GetDatabase("WatchTblDB");
            var collection = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("UsersWatchtbls");




            //var documnt = new BsonDocument
            //        {
            //            {"fbId",""},
            //            {"Name",NameTxt.Text.ToString()},
            //            {"pass",PasswTxt.Text.ToString()},
            //        };

            var documntFirst = new BsonDocument();
            BsonDocument arrtWtchtbl = new BsonDocument();
            BsonArray arrSym = new BsonArray();



            arrtWtchtbl.Add("wid", "");
            arrtWtchtbl.Add("name", "");

            arrSym.Add(new BsonDocument("Name", ""));
            arrtWtchtbl.Add("Symboles", arrSym);


            documntFirst.Add("fbId", "");
            documntFirst.Add("Name", NameTxt.Text.ToString());
            documntFirst.Add("pass", PasswTxt.Text.ToString());
            documntFirst.Add("Watchtbl", arrtWtchtbl);

            var count = 0;
            var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Name", NameTxt.Text.ToString());
            using (var cursor = await collection.FindAsync(filter))
            {
                while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
                {
                    var batch = cursor.Current;
                    foreach (var document in batch)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (count > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Pseudo exists, Write anotheer Pseudo");
            }
            else
            {
                await collection.InsertOneAsync(documntFirst);
                MessageBox.Show("Register complete, log In Plz");
                Form logInfrm = new LogIn();
                logInfrm.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I am deserialize data into list using this code :

```
private async void BindData()
    {
        try
        {
            //connect to MongoDB
            var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://servername:27017");

            //Get the Database
            var database = client.GetDatabase("WatchTblDB");

            //Get the Collection
            var collectionWatchtbl = database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("UsersWatchtbls");

            //Insert Colelction into List
            var filter = new BsonDocument();
            var cursor = collectionWatchtbl.FindAsync(filter).Result;
            await cursor.ForEachAsync(batch =>
            {
                user.Add(BsonSerializer.Deserialize<UserWatchTblCls>(batch));
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

    }
```

If I try to show the data in a Master/details GridView and the Watchtbl is null or not like the structure of collection that I am using it will show an error Null Exception

```
private void Detail_BindData()
    {
        //insert in details DataGridView Data
        foreach (var row in DataClass.OrderMasterBindClass.objMasterDGVBind)
        {
            var rowId = row.User_ID.ToString();
            foreach (var itemUser in user)
            {
                if (rowId == itemUser.Id.ToString())
                {
                    foreach (var itemWtch in itemUser.WatchTbls)
                    {
                        builder = new StringBuilder();
                        foreach (var itemSym in itemWtch.Symbols)
                        {
                            builder.Append(itemSym.Name.ToString()).Append(" | ");
                        }
                        DataClass.OrderDetailBindClass obj1 = new DataClass.OrderDetailBindClass(itemUser.Id.ToString(), itemWtch.WID.ToString(), itemWtch.Name.ToString(), builder.ToString());
                        DataClass.OrderDetailBindClass.objDetailDGVBind.Add(obj1);

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**Update (Solution)**
Just I modify this code for insert data into collection

```
var doct = new BsonDocument
            {
                { "fbId", "7854" },
                { "Name", NameTxt.Text.ToString() },
                { "pass", PasswTxt.Text.ToString() },
                { "Watchtbl", new BsonArray
                                {
                                    new BsonDocument
                                    {
                                        { "wid", "745" },
                                        { "name", "azs" },
                                        { "Symboles", new BsonArray
                                                        {
                                                            new BsonDocument
                                                            {
                                                                { "Name", "nbv" }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                        }
                                    }
                                } 
                }

            };
```